# How the html5 works as a cross platform?

Tags: android, html, cordova, nfc

I am currently looking for a cross platform technolgy for my Android App, I come to conclusion of HTML5,I tried some sample code and some Native applications using PhoneGap.
I'm little confused about Native Application(Using PhoneGap),It Uses .java files for writting plugins for Android, now if I want to develope same App for Windows,should i need to create new plugins for windows phone?.
(I'm working on NFC project in android.The plugins for NFC in android are available at

http://phonegap.com/2011/09/26/building-an-nfc-enabled-android-application-with-phonegap/
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You will need to create plugins for different platforms that you use. You can use the base set of API's everywhere but if something does not exist, then you'll have to create a plugin for it in the platform's native language. You can contribute these plugins as open source back tot he community so others can use it as well.

See the plugin development guide here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html